# Can row_number() ignore null in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data like this

```
---------------------------
|   code    | other column
---------------------------
|   C       |    a
|   null    |    a
|   A       |    a
|   null    |    a
|   null    |    a
----------------------------
```

How can i write query to get row_number without counting null column.

```
----------------------------------
| id  |   code    | other column |
----------------------------------
| 1   |   C       |    a
|     |   null    |    a
| 2   |   A       |    a
|     |   null    |    a
|     |   null    |    a
----------------------------------
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, not specifically.  But you can get what you want by using conditional logic:

```
select (case when code is not null
             then row_number() over (partition by (case when code is not null then 1 else 0 end)
                                     order by . . .
                                    )
        end) as id
```

It is not clear to me what the `order by` is for the `row_number()` which is what the `. . .` means.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to order on code (descendent in your example)  with NULLs last:

```
select 
  decode(code,null,null,row_number() over (order by code DESC NULLS LAST)) rn,
  code
from test;
```

If you need to order on OTHER column:

```
select 
  decode(code,null,null,row_number() over (order by decode(code,null,null,'x')  NULLS LAST, other DESC)) rn,
  code, other
from test;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another easy way would be:

```
Select 
CASE WHEN code IS NOT NULL THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY code order by code) 
     ELSE NULL END id,
 code,
 other_column
FROM table;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use row_number on the desired subset and then union all the other records:

```
select row_number() over (order by sortkey) as id, code, other_column
from mytable
where code is not null
union all
select null as id, code, other_column
from mytable
where code is null
order by sortkey;
```

Answer (score 0):

Example, in my case using IS NOT NULL did not work for me, I had to change it to an expression:

```
SELECT A.ITEMNAME,
       CASE
          WHEN (SELECT T1.MAXSTOCK
                  FROM DATOS T1
                 WHERE T1.MAXSTOCK) > 5 THEN
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CASE
                               WHEN (SELECT T1.MAXSTOCK
                                       FROM DATOS T1
                                      WHERE T1.MAXSTOCK) <= 5 /*here should go IS NOT NULL*/
                                THEN
                                1
                             END ORDER BY A.ITEMNAME)
          ELSE
           NULL
        END AS #ROW
  FROM TABLE A
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).